# Parsing DynamoDB Request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My goal is to recursively parse a `DynamoDB` request from `dynamo.getItem` method.

Unfortunately, I can't find similar method in DynamoDB SDK for Node.js.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html

I am looking for an effective way of removing types from the result. In DynamoDB, keys are one-letter names of properties, like "N", "S", "M".

Description of these types:

```
N means DynamoDB Number type
S means dynamoDB String type
M means DynamoDB Map type (object with properties)
```

Current JSON structure is:

```
{  
  "id":{  
    "N":"4"
  },
  "number":{  
    "N":"1"
  },
  "data":{  
    "M":{  
      "aaa":{  
        "S":"AAA"
      },
      "lv2":{  
        "M":{  
          "lv3":{  
            "M":{  
              "ccc":{  
                "N":"111"
              }
            }
          },
          "bbb":{  
            "S":"BBB"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need a JavaScript function that maps the above JSON into a shorter version:

```
{  
    "id": "4",
    "number": "1",
    "data": { 
        "aaa": "AAA",
        "lv2": {    
            "lv3": { 
                "ccc": "111"
            },
            "bbb": "BBB"
        }
    }
}
```

It is generally a JavaScript question, but I suppose folks with DynamoDB experience might know how to deal with this issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

aws-sdk now offers support to marshall/unmarshall data with `AWS.DynamoDB.Converter`.
See docs here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html

Update 1/7/2018: This converter code is built into `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` so there's no need to use `Converter.marshall` and `Converter.Unmarshall` directly. See:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're using node, there's a cool package that does the dynamo-to-json marshalling and unmarshalling that worked great for me:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-marshaler

**Basic Marshaling of Objects**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var marshalItem = require('dynamodb-marshaler').marshalItem;

AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
var dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

dynamoDb.putItem({
  TableName: 'users',
  Item: marshalItem({username: 'nackjicholson'})  // {username: {S: 'nackjicholson'}} 
});
```

**Basic Unmarshaling of Objects**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var unmarshalItem = require('dynamodb-marshaler').unmarshalItem;

AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
var dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var data = dynamoDb.scan({
  TableName: 'users'
}, function(err, data) {
  // data.Items = [{username: {S: 'nackjicholson'}] 
  var items = data.Items.map(unmarshalItem);
  console.log(items); // [{username: 'nackjicholson'}] 
});
```

Comment: This package has been incorporated into aws-sdk: 
`AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(data.Item);`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/index.html) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb)), then you can pair it with the `unmarshall` method from [@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb).

For example:

```js
const { DynamoDBClient, GetItemCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { marshall, unmarshall } = require("@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb");

(async () => {
  const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "eu-west-2" });
  const params = {
    Key: marshall({
      HashKey: "KeyName",
    }),
    TableName: "my-table",
  };
  const command = new GetItemCommand(params);
  const { Item } = await client.send(command);
  const POJO = unmarshall(Item); // POJO is without types :)
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

*Answering for this question very late, Hope it will help others in future.*

AWS provides schema based library for DynamoDb, It supports data mapper, data mapper annotation, projection expression, data marshaling and un marshaling.

[Amazon DynamoDB DataMapper For JavaScript](https://awslabs.github.io/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/)

Sample Snippet

```
import {
    attribute,
    autoGeneratedHashKey,
    rangeKey,
    table,
    versionAttribute,
} from '@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper-annotations';

@table('my_table')
class MyDomainClass {
    @autoGeneratedHashKey()
    id: string;

    @rangeKey({defaultProvider: () => new Date()})
    createdAt: Date;

    @versionAttribute()
    version: number;

    @attribute()
    toggle?: boolean;

    @attribute({memberType: 'String'})
    tags?: Set<string>;

    // This property will not be saved to DynamoDB.
    notPersistedToDynamoDb: string;
}

// fetch an object
const toGet = new MyDomainClass();
toGet.id = 'ID_TO_FETCH';
const fetched = await mapper.get(toGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is create your custom map:

```
const items = data.Items.map(
    (item) => {
        return {
            id: item.id.N,
            number: item.number.N,
            data: {
               aaa: item.data.M.aaa.S,
               lv2: {
                   lv3: {
                       ccc: item.data.M.lv2.M.lv3.M.ccc.N
                   },
                   bbb: item.data.M.lv2.M.bbb.S
               }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `dynamodb` data using two methods.
one is parsing without using mapping function.

```
{
  roll no: 10
  Id: 2
  Name: {
    "S": "Ankit"
  }
  empId:{ 
    "N": "152"
  }
  edu: {
    "S": "postGraduate"
  }
  Add:{ 
    "S":"Delhi"
  }
  phone: { 
    "N": "941354"
  }
  nationality: { 
    "S": "India"
  }
}
```

We can simply `unmarshal` such data with `AWS.Dynamodb.Converter.Unmarshal`.

```
const result = {
  ...AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(message),
  ...message.description,
  primary_key: message.primary_key,
  sort_key: message.sort_key,
};
return {
  body: JSON.stringify(result)
}
```